# Is there such a thing as a "Live-USB rot"?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb

I commonly utilize live USBs for either diagnosing issues or to just use an untrusted machine.

My live USB setup is generally `dd` it to a USB drive, so it looks like this:

```
root@localhost:~# lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME       RM   SIZE   RO   TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sdb         1   7.5G    0   disk
|_sdb1      1   4.6G    0   part   /run/archiso/bootmnt
```

No extra partitions made, write-only in a sense.

Will this live USB, if I never `dd` another ISO to it again, rot or wear out due to write-cycles?

Furthermore, if the power was suddenly cut off while running in this live environment, can I expect any harm to come to the drive?  Such as a tool failing to run later, some form of corruption?

Comment: Do you mean "read-only", since you're *not* writing to them?

Comment: See [Flash Corruption](http://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/lattice-semiconductor-220/pdf/lattice-wp-flash-corruption.pdf) and [Understanding the Impact of Power Loss on Flash Memory](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~swanson/papers/DAC2011PowerCut.pdf). Also google "NAND read disturb" e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Read_disturb.

Answer (score 0):

Most cheap USB drives & other flash media (cards like SD/CF, etc) have estimated "lifetime writes" of 1,000 or 10,000 or maybe even 100,000 so it sounds like you're trying to avoid writes to keep them useable for as long as possible.

Writing a static ISO and booting live should minimize writes, as long as you don't have a "persistent" file or partition (there used to be a long-standing bug where persistent data would get corrupted eventually, not sure if it still exists). If you have the RAM and want to go even further, you could boot with `toram` (copying the ISO to ram) and then unmount, "eject," "power off" or even remove the drive/card (keep in mind memory cards & USB devices physical connectors will wear out too, maybe even in as little as 1,000 "insertion cycles")

I run live all the time, usually the partition is mounted read-write (`rw`) at boot time. Depending on the filesystem some data could still be written then, just for the mount/unmount, for example

- ext2/3/4 records the last mount time, last write time, last mounted on path, mount count, lifetime writes, and a "needs recovery" ("flag" that's cleared when it's unmounted successfully) so some small writes will still occur. Even with unsafe removal or power failures, ext3 (with journaling) never had any serious corruption that a quick `fsck` didn't fix, beyond the last couple files that were being written while interrupted.
- FAT - I'm not sure, how much is written when only mounted & read, but anecdotally I've had nothing but bad luck with FAT filesystems becoming corrupted after a few months of use, with no power failures. (Not just a few files corrupted either, the filesystem was "un-fixable" and every filename being lost, if recovery was even possible with other tools)
- ISO9660 I *think* nothing is written, since it's a read-only filesystem. UDF probably also read-only (but don't quote me on that one)

I've also noticed a strange habit at boot where *only sometimes* other partitions will also be momentarily mounted (read-write) and then unmounted before everything's finished loading. Seems almost like a bug. Search your `/var/log/syslog` for early "mount" (like mounting/mounted).

Even trying the read-only boot option (`ro`) doesn't seem to stop the read-write mounting at boot time.

---

FYI, I personally don't like the raw `dd` of an ISO onto a flash drive, it essentially wastes the rest of the space (since most ISO's are maybe 1GB or 2GB, and apparently the smallest drive you can buy now seems to be 4GB). If you partitioned it you could have a boot partition (still in a read-only filesystem like ISO9660) with GRUB booting the ISO file(s) directly (great for multi-boot drives with multiple ISO's) and also have a data partition(s) in a writeable filesystem to use later.

Also some flash drives are specially formatted to take best advantage of the drive's "blocks", and completely wiping it out with `dd` loses that formatting (it *may* be best to align to MB's (1024-byte, sometimes called MiB's) for reasons to do with erase block & write block sizes (google would be more eloquent explaining it than I).

Comment: Thank you for your quick and very knowledgeable reply!  To the point on the ISO9660 fs, this is what my live-usb is using.  If a partition is read-only, can data still be corrupted due to sudden power loss?  Is it possible for my liveusb to be damaged in this way?

I at first thought it would be like a live-dvd, but when you put in the fact that it's a usb-storage device with the ablility to be written to multiple times, I thought I would get a more-knowledgeable opinion.  Thank you again.

Comment: I don't *think* a USB should normally be damaged just from turning off the power (or unplugging it), as long as nothing's being written then. But, if the power were to be turned off & on repeatedly, very fast (or especially if the voltage were too low or high) then I could see something going wrong. They're really quite complicated little devices, with a micro-controller and "firmware" to decide what flash memory to "pretend" to expose as a useable block, and to swap out failing memory for spares that are still good. Even MicroSD cards have them, like a tiny computer